# Do we have any cli/api to check openstack development version

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

Do we have any cli/api to check openstack development version..i mean whether my system installed havana or grizzly.I searched the openstack cli/api docs but i don't find any relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenStack has a number of elements if you want to verify state.

Each of the component projects and each of the python-client api bindings have their own versions.  Then there are configurable options for addressing API versions in REST queries.

I took a crack at building an API for the very purpose of verifying this data as well as all python dependencies a while back with the aim of cross verifying that against a vulnerability database but I simply haven't had the time to bring it to completion.

This would be a very useful feature I think.

You might look at your pip requires if you installed from source.  Alternatively you can follow the debian package version chain from dependencies and that should provide good insight into what is installed on your system though it's not exactly verified.